# Play each frame once at fixed rate in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I have a bunch of videos at various frame rates, some with variable frame rate.

1. First, I wish to play back every frame only once, at 24 fps, no exceptions. I do not want any extra frames or dropped frames. I know that the play length may well change, and audio is unimportant.
2. Next, I wish to do the above after having thrown out all duplicate frames.

Here's what I've been using in a Windows batch file. It almost always works, but for some videos I've caught it dropping a frame:

```batch
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -y -i "%%i" -an -c copy -f h264 "%%i.h264"

for %%i in (*.h264) do ffmpeg -y -r 24 -i "%%i" -c copy "%%i.R.mp4"

for %%i in (*.R.mp4) do ffmpeg -y -i "%%i"  -b:v 40M -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/24/TB "MPD%%i.mp4"
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The dropped frames do greatly differ from the previous frames so it's not just mpdecimate at work.

Answer (score 0):

The [mpdecimate filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) drops frames that do not differ greatly from the previous frame, that may be the reason why the frames are dropping.

Comment: I should have clarified: the dropped frames do greatly differ.